# Save into dynamic CSV file name through SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, export-to-csv

I have this code that I need to export to multiple CSV file names from (Original-Database) and based on (ID-Database) through coding

Can someone help me with it since I could not find a method to export to CSV in which the file name is variable

ID-Database contains Row Number and associated ID and it's created just to quantify the while loop in the query

The following code selects the tables that I want to export. but I need to actually export it. However, I couldn't find a feasible solution to this problem.

Thanks for helping

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 0;
WHILE @counter <= (SELECT max([RowNum]) FROM (ID-Database)) 
BEGIN

Select* 
From  (Original_DataBase)
Where [ID] = (Select [ID] from (ID-Database) where [RowNum]=@counter) 

  SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

The results should be CSV files with different names that I can determine through the SQL code

Comment: It's not easy to export to an external file from within SQL code. it's easier to pull it out using an external program such as BCP or Powershell. BTW the code you have doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: I am trying to export a big database into multiple CSV files. Each CSV file would have the name of the ID.

The RowNum is just to quantify the ID order for the While Loop.

I tried external tools in Python, but there was an out of memory problems since it is a huge database. That's why I am using this approach.

Comment: In your example you have a table called "MyDatabase" and you are looping around exporting what seems like individual rows. Are you trying to split a table into multiple files? You know a CSV can be as big as you like, it's just opening it in Excel that is the problem. Please explain what you are actually trying to achieve. Why won't a SQL Server Backup do what you need? What is using the CSV files? The easiest way to get data out as files for use by SQL Server is to use `BCP.exe`  with native format

Comment: From pure SQL code you basically can't export files. Well you probably can but it is so convoluted it's never been a practical solution

Comment: I edited the post since there was a problem. There is (original Database) that I want to divide and there is (ID database) that I created for While Loop Purpose.      What I have is 300 Million Rows of (Original Database) that have around 1700 IDs and it is distributed equally for each ID. Therefore, I want to divide (Original Database) into around 1700 CSV files. Each of these small CSV files has 300 Million/1700 rows. I tried multiple approaches through Python, but an out-of-memory problems occurred.

Comment: What is importing the CSV's on the other side?

Comment: It is a table in a database on the server that I was working on and ended up with 300 Million rows

Comment: After you have the CSV files, what are you going to do with them?

Comment: I am using Python for analyzing the smaller databases! It is another day problem

Comment: Why don't you connect directly to the database and analyse with python? I wont't suggest any solution until I understand what you are _really_ trying to do. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: To second @Nick.McDermaid, This sounds a bit like the [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please try to explain a bit more about your goal and which tools might be used... This does not sound a like a pure T-SQL issue...